# VB. How to search a column in excel and return "OK" or give me two options to enter if the column contains certain text

Tags: excel, vba

I am abit of a VB noob. I have a spreadsheet where I am trying to reference column H and return text "NPC" or "Stone" into Column J if H equals either of these values. If column H equals "Ad-hoc" I would like to be able to select either "NPC" or "Stone"and return this value into column J.

Hope this makes sense and someone can help.

Unfortunately I cannot post an image of this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    For Each r In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("H:H"))
        v = r.Value
        If v = "NPC" Or v = "Stone" Then r.Offset(0, 2) = "OK"
        If v = "Ad-hoc" Then r.Offset(0, 2) = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter value", Type:=2)
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with a function approach:

```
    Function npc_or_stone(s As String) As String
        Select Case s
            Case "NPC", "Stone"
                npc_or_stone = s
            Case "Ad-hoc"
                If msg_yes_no("do you want to set it to npc?") Then
                    npc_or_stone = "NPC"
                Else
                    npc_or_stone = "Stone"
                End If
        End Select
    End Function

    Function msg_yes_no(s As String) As Boolean
        msg_yes_no = (MsgBox(s, vbYesNo) = vbYes)
    End Function
```

All you would need to do is add this code to the module of the workbook, then, assuming that there is a header row, you'd enter the following formula in J2:

```
    =npc_or_stone(H2)
```

Then fill the formula down. When you do so, it will ask you what you want to set each blank to when "Ad-hoc" is encountered. From then on, it will only ask you again, if you change a value in column H to "Ad-hoc".

Hope this helps~

Comment: It just occurred to me that if there a lot of lines, this function won't tell you which line it's looking at while asking you which one to pick. So instead of filling down, it might make sense to copy and paste one at a time.